# the onmouseover function doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have a table with this cell:

```
    <td>
        <DIV align='center' onmouseover='dettaglio(<?php echo $cdclie;?>)' onmouseout='chiudiDettaglio()'>0</DIV>
    </td>
```

and I have the javascript:

```js
<script>
// codice per mostrare il dettaglio
function dettaglio()
{
    tooltip = '<div class="tooltiptopicevent" style="width:auto;height:auto;background:#feb811;position:absolute;z-index:10001;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px ;  line-height: 200%;">'
            + 'Client' + ' ' + 'First and last name' + '</div>';

    $("body").append(tooltip);
    $(this).mouseover(function (e)
    {
        $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
        $('.tooltiptopicevent').fadeIn('500');
        $('.tooltiptopicevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
    }).mousemove(function (e)
    {
        $('.tooltiptopicevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
        $('.tooltiptopicevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
    });
}
//  
function chiudiDettaglio()
{
    $(this).css('z-index', 8);
    $('.tooltiptopicevent').remove();
}
</script>
```

In the javascript, I plan on calling AJAX to retrieve a JSON object which will then be displayed by the onmouseover function.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a question. What *is* the expected behaviour? What did you try? And what happened?

Answer (score 1):

You had better start by adding listeners differently:

```
<div class="codice-cliente" align='center' data-clie="<?php echo $cdclie; ?>">0</div>
```

Now in the javascript you add the listeners:

```
$('.codice-cliente').on('mouseover', function(event) {

    // First step. Check if you can see this. Remove if it works.
    $(this).css({ backgroundColor: 'red' });

    // Then proceed. Here you recover the codice-cliente.
    var cdclie = $(this).attr('data-clie');

    console.log("Codice cliente recuperato: ", cdclie);

    // Here your AJAX call. THIS function stops here. The rest
    // will need to be done by a callback.
    $.post(
        '/dettaglio/cliente.php',
        { codice: cdclie },
        function(risposta) {
            console.log('risposta del server', risposta);

            // Here you add the tooltip control code.
        }
    );
});
```

The `cliente.php` script will receive `$_POST['codice']`.

Using Firebug or Chrome Developers Tools, you can inspect the console logs and verify that it worked, or why it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

$(this) can be used inside for example callback function but not in global scope ( this is **window object** there ). Change it in dettaglio and chiudiDettaglio to some selector for example $("table").

Answer (score 0):

jQuery AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ is your friend.

In essence you can send request body or query params to the server.

Assuming there is PHP executing, which might plainly return some JSON via straight echo .... 
You either marshall/unmarshall with a library or do the domain object to json yourself.Just for the terminology. So you can grab it and talk with other experts more easily.

In your JS you can have (maybe you certainly should) a callback defined (read the jquery AJAX api description) it is waiting for you.

You could take the $(selector) jQuery Object thing you already know and "inject" the json from the server into the dom/html element.

And maybe check serialization and marshalling for overall convenience.
And ....